# How to get an Element bind from a svelte component

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I need the bounding client rect of an anchor element.

I mark that using `bind:this={someVariable}`

But when I add that code to a svelte component, I get some other object svelte uses to represent a component.

can I access the enclosed element or something like that from that binding?
Or do I have to wrap every component with a sacrificial `<div />` and bind that?

Comment: i spent my lunch break designing tshirts for the band, "sacrificial `<div / >`" cheers

Answer (score 8):

Using `bind:this` does not give you a DOM Element because Svelte does not require that your component has a root element. This is a valid Svelte element:

```html
<script>
 ...
</script>
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

And so is a component that does not have any markup at all:

```html
<script>
 ...
</script>
```

In both those cases, it would be impossible to return a bounding client rect for these components because there is no 'root' element.

That said, what you can do is add a `bind:this` in your component and export that one:

```html
<script>
  export let anchor
</script>

<svelte:options accessors></svelte:options>
<a bind:this={anchor}>...</a>
```

And in your parent you can now get the anchor element using `child.anchor` (note that by default the props are not accessible this way, that's why you need the svelte:options)

One of the reason this is not so straightforward though is that it is a very 'unsvelte' way of working, you would normally not direcly interact with the markup generated by another component (that is the domain of that component).

Alternatives could be

- expose the client rectangle directly instead of the element
- move what you are trying to do to the anchor component itself